# How to target an object in a div in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, object

I'm trying to put a piece of data into a javascript variable and I don't know how to target it. The data is in an object that is part of a div. Here's how it looks in the html page

[image: html code to target]

I've highlighted the item I'm trying to target.

Here's what I was trying (and failing with):

```
let dataDiv = document.querySelector(" .bc-product-form__options  > div : data-variants");
console.log( dataDiv : data-variants);
```

How do I get that object into a js variable?

Comment: post the html and json here

Comment: Copy paste that log in your question. (Don't use *only* images.)

Comment: you must use `querySelector().dataset.variants` your selector of `:data-variants` is the ugly part of *jQuery*. You are mixing vanilla with jQ. Try these: `let dataDiv = document.querySelector(".bc-product-form__options > div[data-variants]"); `

Comment: This works: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/csk2p6m5/

Answer (score 2):

You can just select the div by the appropriate attribute (in this case you want `data-js="product-variants-object"` and then use `getAttribute` and `JSON.parse` to retrieve and parse the data.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div[data-js="product-variants-object"]');
let data = JSON.parse(div.getAttribute('data-variants'));
console.log(data);
```

```html
<div data-js="product-variants-object" data-variants='[{"key": "value"}]'></div>
```

Comment: P.S: @Kal - and than, if needed, after you change/modify the `data`, to rebuild, you simply do `div.setAttribute('data-variants', JSON.stringify(data))` :D